# Web-API не распознает некоторые запросы от ВК. ASP.NET Core, Post запрос

Tags: vkontakte-api, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, vknet

Вот фрагмент контроллера, который должен обрабатывать входящие POST запросы от вк. Запрос на подтверждение сервера (confirmation) он принимает и обрабатывает, но запрос при новом сообщении в сообщество он не видит(message_new).
Фрагмент контроллера:

'

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Callback([FromBody] Updates updates)
{
    // Проверяем, что находится в поле "type" 
    switch (updates.Type)
    {
        // Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса
        case "confirmation":
            // Отправляем строку для подтверждения 
            return Ok(_configuration["Config:Confirmation"]);
        case "message_new":
            // Десериализация

            var msg = Message.FromJson(new VkResponse(updates.Object));

            // Отправим в ответ полученный от пользователя текст
            _vkApi.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
            {
                RandomId = new DateTime().Millisecond,
                PeerId = msg.PeerId.Value,
                Message = msg.Text
            });
            break;
    }
    // Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API
    return Ok("ok");
}
```

'

Кто знает, в чем дело может быть?